# Column Chooser does not play well with too many columns having autoresizeOnLoad or autoresizable

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Demo is found at ...

I noticed 2 issues.

1) In Column Chooser dialog, I can't drag 'n drop the column name bar to other box.

2) Click on "-" icon for VIN and Year column then click "OK" button.  The column header is unable to resize.   So, how do I do autoresizeOnLoad to false for Column Chooser if that's the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use already `done` callback of `columnChooser` and you call

```js
this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
```

explicitly in your code. What you need to do is to add the call

```js
this.jqGrid("autoResizeAllColumns");
```

directly after calling of `remapColumns`. `autoresizeOnLoad:true` just call `autoResizeAllColumns`, but it do this **on reloading of the grid**. You want to do autoresizing after the usage of `columnChooser` instead.

One more possible implementation would be to use the following event handler:

```js
$("#BatchReportJqgrid_Spreadsheet").bind("jqGridRemapColumns", function () {
    $(this).jqGrid("autoResizeAllColumns");
});
```

The last code calls `autoResizeAllColumns` after every call of `remapColumns` method. So you could remove unneeded `done` callback from the list of parameters of `columnChooser` and don't call `remapColumns` explicitly. The method `columnChooser` will call the method, but the above event handler of `"jqGridRemapColumns"` event could still resize the columns at the end of column remapping.

**UPDATE**: It's better if you post JSFiddle demo next time. One will be able to make some changes in your code and retry the changes.

It seems to me that one don't need to do any changes described above and just use `shrinkToFit: false` option of jqGrid. It will prevent changing the width of columns on hiding a column of jqGrid.

Comment: Hmmm.   I tried the 1st half of your suggestion and no new changes is noticable.   So, I tried the 2nd half of your suggestion and still, no new changes is noticable.   Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @fletchsod: See **UPDATED** part of my answer. You need just add `shrinkToFit: false` option of jqGrid. After that the additional call of `autoResizeAllColumns` inside of `jqGridRemapColumns` handler will be not needed.

Comment: I would never have guess `shrinkToFit: false` would be the one.

Comment: @fletchsod: If you don't use `shrinkToFit: false` then the width of columns will be re-calculated based on the `width` defined in columns (default value 150). Because you set `width` of the grid then the column width should be shrinked based on column `width` used as proportions. If you don't specify total `width` of the grid or if you use `shrinkToFit: false` then no shrinking take place.